# inserted elements to the first page of \part{}

Tags: parts

I would like to insert quotations to first pages devoted to `\part{}`
of a document at the bottom right as shown in the picture below.

Could you help me?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This just can't be answered as it stands. We have no idea what class you are using or whether you've already customised sectioning at all...

Answer (score 2):

The following method should work independent of the document class.
The output page of the part page is manipulated via package `atbegshi` to add the part note at the lower right corner of the text area.

First macro `\partnote` ensures, that the current page will be the part page by calling `\cleardoublepage` (flushing of floats, emitting an even numbered fill page depending on the document class settings). Then the node is placed via `\AtBeginShipoutNext` on the next output page.

`\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft` starts a `picture` environment at the upper left corner of the page. The `\put` commands move to the lower right corner of the text area using e-TeX's `\dimexpr` for calculations. Package `picture` allows the specification of dimen or length values in `picture`'s commands (e.g. `\put).

The following example also shows frames to visualize the page layout via option `showframe` of package `geometry`. (Option `pass` means that the current layout settings are not changed by package `geometry`.)

The full example file:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, landscape]{article}
% Options a5paper and landscape to get a smaller image for TeX.SX
\usepackage[pass, showframe]{geometry}% only for the frame

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{picture}

\newcommand*{\partnotefont}{\itshape}
\newcommand{\partnote}[1]{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \AtBeginShipoutNext{%
    \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
      \put(\dimexpr\ifodd\value{page}\oddsidemargin\else\evensidemargin\fi
        + 1in + \textwidth\relax,
        -\dimexpr\topmargin + 1in + \headheight + \headsep + \textheight){%
        \makebox(0,0)[rb]{%
          \partnotefont
          \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
        }%
      }%  
    }%  
  }
}

\begin{document}

  \partnote{%
    Necessity of the method in the search for truth\\
    Ren\'e Descartes (1596--1650)
  }
  \part{Tintin in America}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Refinement

TeX allows the depth of the lowest box on a page to stick into the bottom margin. The amount is limited by `\maxdepth`. The following refinement measures the depth of the bottom line of the box and allows it to stick into the bottom margin:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}% only for the frame

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newcommand*{\partnodefont}{\itshape}
\newcommand{\partnote}[1]{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \AtBeginShipoutNext{%
    \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
      \put(\dimexpr\ifodd\value{page}\oddsidemargin\else\evensidemargin\fi
        + 1in + \textwidth\relax,
        -\dimexpr\topmargin + 1in + \headheight + \headsep + \textheight){%
        \makebox(0,0)[rb]{%
          \partnodefont
          \sbox0{\begin{varwidth}[b]{\linewidth}\centering#1\end{varwidth}}%
          \ifdim\dp0>0pt
            \dp0=\dimexpr\dp0 - \ifdim\dp0>\maxdepth \maxdepth\else\dp0 \fi    
          \fi
          \usebox{0}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }
}

\begin{document}

  \partnote{%
    Necessity of the method in the search for truth\\
    Ren\'e Descartes (1596--1650)
  }
  \part{Tintin in America}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result refinement]

The base line of the note's lower line is now at the bottom of the text area.